# How Change Telerik RadGrid Column's Property Server-Side 

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a TemplateColumn in my telerik radgird like below :

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Commands column"
                                HeaderText="Commands" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Commands"
                                AllowFiltering="False" Display="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="False"
                                        CssClass="lb">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

i want to change display(or visible) property of this column server-side.
which event should i use and how can i do that?
**Edit:**
there is a button and a textbox and after click on that bottun i checked that text box text and if it be ok i want to change that display(or visible) property of that column(delete acction should be available only for admin with administrator username string) 
that button is outside of that grid.

thanks in advance

Comment: There are many times when that property can change.  OnItemCommand, OnItemCreated, OnItemDataBound, OnNeedDataSource.  Can you give more details on your specific scenario?

Comment: Also, please be aware of the difference between 'Display' and 'Visible'... http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/visible-vs-display-on-grid-column-definition.aspx

Comment: hi, there is a button and a textbox and after click on that bottun i checked that text box text and if it be ok i want to change that display property of that column(delete acction should be available only for admin with administrator username string)

Comment: If the button is part of the row, I would use ItemCommand.  If the button is not in the grid I would suggest OnNeedDataSource

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive i think i should use visible instead of display. thanks for that link.

Comment: that button in outside of that grid.

Comment: @Downvoter -> is my q clear now?  so sorry for the loss of information.

Comment: hello -> GlennFerrieLive where are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like below. after binding telerik rad grid in server side code

```
grdDemo.DataSource = ds
grdDemo.DataBind()

grdDemo.MasterTableView.GetColumn("TemplateColumn_Commands").Display = False
```

it should resolve your issue. happy coding

Comment: i test your codes in itemDataBound event -> for visible property -> does not work.

Comment: you dont need to place this code in any events. its works as beyond to event. just need to check in which condition you need to change the display property. if is there any condition under you want to change property please write "grdDemo.MasterTableView.GetColumn("TemplateColumn_Commands").Display = False" under the condition as per your need.